# Difference between + operator and append function for string class object in c++?

Tags: c++, string

We can add two string class object let's say

```
string str1="hello"
string str2="world"

string final =str1+str2;
```

or

```
string f=str1.append(str2);
```

What is the difference between these two methods?? 
order in which they add or implementation or anything else??

Comment: Have you tried those snippets and compared the contents of `str1` and `str2` in both cases?

Comment: Also, `operator+` will be implicitly invoked, so lets say when you have templates and parse arguments of type T, you can simply use the `+`-operator and do not need to specialize that template for concrete datatypes. There are definitely other opportunities where an implicit call  may be useful. Though you should be aware that an implicit call can always mean less control...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

operator+ will add two strings together and generate a new string with the value. Where as append will take a string and concatenate to the end of your string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str = "Writing";
  string str2= " a book";
  str.append(str2);                      
  cout << str << endl;  // "Writing a book"
  return 0;
}
```

Also, append has more features like only append a part of that string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str;
  string str2="Writing ";
  string str3="print 10 and then 5 more";

  // used in the same order as described above:
  str.append(str2);                       // "Writing "
  str.append(str3,6,3);                   // "10 "
  str.append("dots are cool",5);          // "dots "
  str.append("here: ");                   // "here: "
  str.append(10,'.');                     // ".........."
  str.append(str3.begin()+8,str3.end());  // " and then 5 more"
  str.append<int>(5,0x2E);                // "....."

  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

More on [append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously `str1` has different values between the two operations (in the first, it remains the same as before, in the second it has the same value as `f`).

Another difference is `str1 + str2` creates a temporary string (the result of the concatenation) and then applies `operator=`. The `str1.append()` call does not create the temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

For one, `operator+` creates a new string, whereas `append` modifies a previously existing one. So, in your examples, the second one will modify `str1`, and the first one will not. The `append` method is closer to `+=` than to `+`.

Answer (score 0):

in case of + operator it will first take a temporary space then copy the first string in it and then copy the second string afterwards where as in append() 
it directly concatenate the the second string after first string , so append is better in terms of performance no. of copy operations are less